# How to choose NTC thermistor?

Tags: thermistor, ups, inrush-current

I would like to make a siren on an UPS backup. I used this board with an 18650 embedded battery: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32911096857.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.24db4c4dn31JsH

And this siren: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000049267294.html

[image: Setup]

The UPS has an 5V output, and I use a DCDC step-up converter to drive the siren with 12V.

When the UPS is connected to the USB power supply, and the siren triggered, the system is working fine! When the siren is ON, and I remove the USB power supply, everything is still working fine.

However, when I try to trigger the alarm when the USB power plug is disconnected, the UPS goes in security and the siren never start.

I think that it is because of the inrush current of the siren.

I bought a 33 Ohm EPCOS NTC (Ref. B57153S330M51) to add it in series with the siren.

It is working now on the UPS only; however, the siren is not loud as without the NTC. It seems that the resistor value goes too slowly to 0 Ohms.

The consumed current of the siren is about 300-400 mA. How can I choose the right NTC in order to have the loudest sound of my siren after only 1s ?

Thanks for your help!

**Aditionnal informations :**

I have made some voltage measurement on the DCDC output.

**DCDC Output, on USB plug**
[image: DCDC Output, on USB plug]

**DCDC Output, on battery**
[image: DCDC Output, on battery]

My project only use chinese modules, so I have no real datasheets... My schematic :

[image: Schematic with NTC]

**Siren consumption under 12 V :** between 0,25 and 0,35A

**Edit 2 : Voltage on the 5V UPS output (yellow curve)**

[image: 5V UPS output (yellow curve)]

Comment: Can we see your schematic?

Comment: Why do you think the siren has a major onrush current?  Can't it just be asking for too much current, period?  I can't get at your siren link.  Can you post the relevant data sheet sections?

Comment: Yes, please, in order to offer any useful advice we need to see the schematics for your board, siren, and battery backup device. If you don't have that documentation and the items are not working properly then you should return the items to the seller. Consider it a lesson learned: always buy from reputable vendors who offer the needed documentation.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I have added a schematic and some informations,

Comment: That's more of a "block diagram" than a schematic. Can you show how your grounds are shared?

Comment: @Scott Seidman : I think of major inrush current because it is working on battery backup when the siren is already on when I unplug the USB power socket!

Comment: What are the current capabilities of your UPS?

Comment: @RonBeyer : I have updated my "block diagram"

Comment: @ScottSeidman : The UPS should deliver 4A under 5V. However, this value is not correct, as for some chinese products, because I tried with passive load, and the UPS is working on battery with a current of 0,85A, but doesn't work with 1,08 A.

Again, it is working when the siren is in it nominal mode, it is only the startup which doesn't work

Comment: Buy. better. products. Trash the stuff you have if it doesn't work.

Comment: The so-called UPS will not do 4A @ 12V  . maybe only the IC's FET switch is rated for 4A peak not DC output.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson : feel free to give me another stuff, I haven't find anything else as small ups with 18650 battery....

Answer (score 0):

Obviously to me is your DCDC convert is unable to meet the inrush current and the NTC is too high impedance.

To solve the problem you need to define some design specs for step load regulation ESR and current limit based on voltage and impedance.  There may be a better bandaid NTC solution but likely inadequate.

- **perhaps a reed relay bypass of NTC is best.** with a closure time of 20 ms where the DCDC has recovered from the step load.

The only siren specs I could find with my english corrections are:

```
Rated voltage: 12V DC
Sound index: 120dB
Sound frequency: 3.8KH2+10%
Transmit speed: 3Hz increase or decrease 10% (me) this is frequency modulated +/-10%
```

**Siren DC resistance**

- Measure it then model the impedance as a RC//R to match test results  with 20ms voltage recovery time of  22ms with USB connection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faWWqq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- I presume this is a magnetic speaker style siren not piezo.
- If it were like a tweeter speaker the DC resistance would be 3/8 of the rated impedance

  - or 3 Ohms DC for an 8 Ohm speaker.
- If it were like a linear motor the DC resistance would be 8 ~ 10% of resonant frequency impedance meaning like a DC motor inrush is 10 ~ 12x the operating current.

### Suggestion

If it were me , I would use a tiny 12V battery with ESR < 100 mOhm charged by "UPS" with a float charge.   This gives the >>> 1 Farad needed with low ESR needed to start the siren.  A Buck then Boost DCDC will never hack it.  Not enough stored energy in a small package and too high ESR.

- fix up all power and signal interfaces to suppress 5V Oscillations from Boost regulator.

  - Start with a transistor active load test to simulate Alarm step load 400mA@12V= 5W .
  - For example disconnect Boost regulator and test with NPN or switch and 0.5 to 2 Ohm resistor with a loop smaller than a C with your fingers.
  - Use 20MHz filter because your probes will have step resonance >20MHz with a long ground lead.
  - Use better EMI techniques for RF interference, Like twisted pairs only. You have an EMI problem easily fixed with experience.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe1tl2.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still doesn't understand why it can be the dcdc converter as it is working when the ups is on the power line?

Comment: Why did you now show the 5V output?  It is shutting off it seems

Comment: The UPS has two output : 3.3V/1A - 5V/4A. I use the 3.3V to power the ESP01, and the 5V to power the DCDC step-up converter which give me a 12V to power the siren.

Graphs above are measured at the 12V DCDC output when I am switching the siren ON.

The first graph is with the USB power connected. We can notice a voltage dip for 20ms, but after that, we come back to the 5V, ans the siren is still working.

The second graph is with the USB power disconnected, so the UPS is on battery. Here, we can see the same voltage dip, but after 10ms, the UPS enter in security mode and switch off.

Comment: Again. Where is the scope trace of the 5V input to DCDC boost conv.?

Comment: Again, when the siren is turned on with the USB power, and I unplug it in order to be on battery supply, the siren is still working. That why I think about an inrush current that the UPS only on battery can't accept.

Comment: OK there are a few disconnects in my understanding. First UPS is used for AC, not DC systems  Your calling it a UPS but its a Li-Ion to 5,3.3V converter with USB charge and control functions and I lost track where your NTC is because its missing on your schematic and I don't know what triggers your security mode except maybe a drop in 5V which you have yet to show.

Comment: Also looking at the layout I think you have a ground drop in voltage on thin wires and the block diagram unconventional logic  is a good explanation for your issues with analog power issues and low impedance power. You want low ESR, low ESL for power . I'm retired and logging out 3:15 am

Comment: I have added the NTC on the block diagram, and the 5V UPS output measurement

Comment: So you can see you have a problem on 5V so fix that . Use proper 10:1 probes and beef up all grounds with flat > 3mm and keep short like inside a cell phone  Add RF caps on all interfaces.. Fix block diagram and layout use short AWG 16 on 5V add low ESR caps, Ferrite isolate from RF Step load

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is really interesting. I am working in EMC domain, but I have only few knowledge about EMC applied on PCB. Unfortunatly, I don't have a lot of components and equipments at my house, and I have returned the scope which was a borrowing. I don't have any low ESR capacitors, neither CM choke, ferrite, ... So with that in mind, and the fact that I would like to keep the setup simple, if the DCDC is a problem, could I replace it with a linear regulator as LM317 to solve the problem ?

Comment: No but you can use heavier power in twisted pair on 5V and get bulk caps from lots of old boards